# Changes in App.config do not reflect after restarting the application

Tags: c#, app-config, appsettings

I am using an app.config file to store the dynamic parameters of my application. The problem is, when I change a value in app.config file, and start the application, it doesn't load the new value from config file. Seems like the values in app.config file are being read and embedded in exe file only at compile time!

This is how I read the config file:

```
public class Helper
{
    static Helper()
    {
        Foo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Foo"];
    }
    public static string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you post the app.config contents?

Comment: also which file are changing the contents of?  the App.config?  or the <exename>.exe.config in the same directory as the application is running in?

Comment: I am changing the content of App.config file by hand.
I will post the structure of my app.config file as a reply to this post.

Comment: then see me answer below.  you are changing the wrong file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you sure you are changing the correct file? You don't want to change the app.config file, but the `<exename>.exe.config` file, in the same directory as the .exe

The app.config file is what you edit in the ide, but when you compile your app this file is renamed to `<exename>.exe.config` and copied to the output directory when you compile.  The .exe looks for a file with the same name as itself with the .config extension when looking for the default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The static nature of your class and method may be causing you the issue.  Maybe refactor it to the following...

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string Foo 
    { 
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Foo"];
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, thinking about it, it doesn't help you a great deal since `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Foo"]` is already (effectively) a static call - you're just adding another layer of abstraction that may well not be required.

Comment: Yes you are right, I guess it might be due to the nature of static properties. Just three poinsts: 1) I made it static so that it doesn't get read from config file each time I read the property. 2) My approach works greatly in web.config file in web apps 3) In case it's the problem of static property, where are the values kept after I close the application and start it again?!

Comment: They're stored in the config file.  The original question has a setter in the member, but IIRC you can't set app.config paramteers from code (unless the behaviour changed and I missed it)

Comment: I am not trying to change the value in the app.config file from code. I am just changing the value by hand. I just don't know why this change is not reflected the next time I run the application. Even if I rename or remove the app.config file, the exe file runs greatly! as if there is no need to read the config file again. As I said, seems like the key values in app.config file are only read in compile time and get embedded in exe file.

Comment: No, they aren't compiled. Try changin your codebase to use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Foo"]` each time and verify the behaviour.  If (when) it works like that, you'll know the problem is within your Helper class.

Comment: Ok, let me try that and I will let you know.

Comment: I should've changed the .exe.config file :)