# Issue reading updated value of settings (app.config)

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I created settings in my winforms app like this: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/nm0owj/8)

You can see I have timer interval value there. With the goal that inside timer here:

```
{
    // Inside timer tick handler
    ....
      finally
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    int tinterval = Properties.Settings.Default.TimerInterval;
                    HelperMethods.AppendToLogFile(tinterval.ToString(), LogType.Information);

                    timer1.Interval = tinterval;
                    timer1.Start();
                }
}
```

I want to change interval value of timer on runtime.

But when I launch the application even if I change the interval inside the app.config file (opened from windows explorer), **still old value is being read inside the timer above**. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Actually this doesn't even work, if I close my application, and start it again (i.e. restart my application). It still reads old values from `app.config` (not the ones I entered after application was shutdown and before application was opened). What am I getting wrong?

**PS. The culprit maybe here, please [see](http://tinypic.com/r/34zad4y/8) - It always reads the old value 1500, instead of 2000. You can see how VS is saying (after I closed and reopened project) that settings file still has old value, what is going on here?**

Comment: Do you mean you want to re-read the app.config at runtime? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335931/save-and-reload-app-configapplicationsettings-at-runtime

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes at run time. I would appreciate if you can provide sample code in my case - where to put that code. Assuming I want to read values of `TimerInterval` and `OracleConnectionString` at run time (user will just manually change the app.config file anytime)

Comment: @CodeCaster: This does not work - even when I closed my application and started it from beginning, new values - which I input in app.config file, are not being read. ?!

Comment: Are you editing the app.config in your bin directory? That gets overwritten every build...

Comment: @CodeCaster: No it is here: C:\Users\gr\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Gateway\Gateway; please see also my update to the question

Comment: @CodeCaster: There is no app.config in my bin directory. Do you have any other advice, I am getting confused

Comment: Write things to text file and read from it if applicable to your situation. Don't use app.config. Configs are for different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the default settings applied, the configuration file for `Settings` is likely saved in the user directory, not the application directory. Thus you're editing the wrong file. That's because the `Scope` value is set to `User` in the settings editor in Visual Studio.

Try finding your application's configuration in `AppData` (usually `Local\YourCorporation\Application_version` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer is here
[Changes in App.config do not reflect after restarting the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913903/changes-in-app-config-do-not-reflect-after-restarting-the-application)

But seeing changes of config file at runtime, I didn't solve and ignoring at this stage.